# How to get property value from .net dynamic array object

Tags: c#, .net, json, linq

I've got a json file containing

```
{
  "Accounts": null,
  "AccountTypes": null,
  "Actions": null,
  "Photos": [
    {
      "Instance": "...",
      "Key": "..."
    },
    ....
  ]
}
```

Now I want to get all the Instance properties from the Photo objects. I've got the following code:

```
var photos = new List<Photo>();

string json = File.ReadAllText(file);
dynamic jsonObj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, typeof(object));
var jsonPhotos = jsonObj.Photos as IEnumerable<dynamic>;
var instances = jsonPhotos.Select(x => x.Instance);

foreach (var instance in instances)
    photos.Add(new Photo
    {
        Document = Convert.FromBase64String(instance)
    });
```

However, jsonPhotos.Select(x => x.Instance); isn't returning anything...

I am able to get things working by using

```
var instances = new List<string>();

foreach (var photo in jsonPhotos)
    instances.Add(photo.Instance.Value);
```

But can I solve this in a LINQ way?

Comment: your json format is wrong. there is a comma missing after "Instance": "...", if you fix it the problem goes away.

Comment: Sorry, the typo only exists in my question here. In my real code there was never a typo

Comment: but `jsonPhotos.Select(x => x.Instance);` does return something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why just don't use `Json.Linq` for that? Parse JSON to [`JObject`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm) instance, then map every token from `Photos` array to `Photo` instance (I've omitted `Convert.FromBase64String` because OP sample doesn't have a valid base64 data, but converting `Instance` value can be easily added)

```cs
var json = JObject.Parse(jsonString);

var photos = json["Photos"]
    .Select(token => new Photo
    {
        Document = token["Instance"]?.Value<string>()
    })
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

The `.Select(x => x.Instance)` indeed returns `...` on .NET Core 3.1. Can you verify that the contents of the `json` variable are actually what you expect?

Specifically

```cs
jsonPhotos.Select(x => x.Instance);
```

works as expected, while

```cs
jsonPhotos.Select(x => x.SomeNonExistingProperty);
```

enumerates nothing / empty values.

---

For example, this code prints `Instance A`, then `Instance B`, then nothing twice:

```cs
var json = @"
{
    ""Photos"": [
    {
        ""Instance"": ""Instance A"",
        ""Key"": ""...""
    },
    {
        ""Instance"": ""Instance B"",
        ""Key"": ""...""
    }]
}";

var jsonObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json);
var jsonPhotos = jsonObj.Photos as IEnumerable<dynamic>;

var instances = jsonPhotos.Select(x => x.Instance);
foreach (var instance in instances)
{
    Console.WriteLine(instance);
}

// In contrast, this one will print empty lines.
instances = jsonPhotos.Select(x => x.SomeNonExistingProperty);
foreach (string instance in instances)
{
    Console.WriteLine(instance);
}
```

I took the liberty to change the deserialization to `dynamic` directly, but it also works with the original code from the question.

Comment: The typo is not the issue, since that one results in a `JsonReaderException`.

Comment: Sorry, the typo only exists in my question. In my real code there is no typo... I've edit my question and fixed the typo